# Unable to Consume Kafka Message using Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-kafka, integration

I am trying to integrate Kafka+Camel and not able to figure out - how to consume a message.

I am trying to create a Consumer using Apache Camel for a topic in Apache Kafka.
I am using Apache Camel 2.18.2 and Kafka 2.10 and JDK 1.8.

Following is the program to produce a message to a topic named - SyncInOut.

```
final String toKafka= "kafka:localhost:9092?topic=SyncInOut&groupId=group1";
final String fromKafka = "kafka:localhost:9092?topic=SyncInOut&groupId=group1&autoOffsetReset=earliest&consumersCount=1";

final String TEST_PAYLOAD = "Sync Payload InOut!";

CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
    Exchange exchange = template.send(toKafka, ExchangePattern.InOut, new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            exchange.getIn().setBody(TEST_PAYLOAD);
        }
    });
```

On executing the code above, I am able to produce messages using ProducerTemplate and the message is successfully pushed to SyncInOut. But I am not able to consume the message. Here, I am adding a new route and trying to consume.

```
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
             public void configure() {
                 PropertiesComponent pc = getContext().getComponent("properties", PropertiesComponent.class);
                 pc.setLocation("classpath:application.properties");

                 log.info("About to start route: Kafka Server -> Log ");

                 from(fromKafka)
                 .process(new Processor() {
                     @Override
                     public void process(Exchange exchange)
                             throws Exception {
                         String messageKey = "";
                         if (exchange.getIn() != null) {
                             Message message = exchange.getIn();
                             Integer partitionId = (Integer) message
                                     .getHeader(KafkaConstants.PARTITION);
                             String topicName = (String) message
                                     .getHeader(KafkaConstants.TOPIC);
                             if (message.getHeader(KafkaConstants.KEY) != null)
                                 messageKey = (String) message
                                         .getHeader(KafkaConstants.KEY);
                             Object data = message.getBody();


                             System.out.println("topicName :: "
                                     + topicName + " partitionId :: "
                                     + partitionId + " messageKey :: "
                                     + messageKey + " message :: "
                                     + data + "\n");
                         }
                     }
                 }).to("log:input");
             }
         });
         camelContext.start();
```

The above Consumer route does not work as expected. Ideally, the message consumed should get printed, but nothing seems to happen. It seems it is not getting triggered that way. So, I tried consuming the message using ConsumerTemplate like below, but that didn't worked either.

```
Exchange exchangeConsumer = consumerTemplate.receive(fromKafka);
    System.out.println("Body is : "+exchangeConsumer.getOut().getBody().toString());
```

The above line never gets completed. I am not able to figure out how to consume a message from Kafka topic using Apache Camel. I could not find much help from the official documentation. Any other help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in the simplest way, using the provided kafka-console-consumer CLI tool, in the kafka bin directory? If that does not consume it, than probably it is not being produced.

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic : I will try consuming from the CLI tool. But I am sure that the message is getting produced as I am able to see it in kafka-tool gui application. I need to know how can I consume that message using apache camel.

Comment: There is a Kafka example at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-kafka. Mind that in 2.19 onwards the kafka uri configuration is changed to configure the topic name and brokers differently

Comment: The example in the docs is for camel 2.17. Try using that and see if it works.

Comment: Also mind about the start method is non-blocking, to keep the JVM running see: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html